Component not rerendering when global state changes. React Redux Toolkit
I'm working on Mafia application for automatizion the gamemaster's work. I have a UserPanel component, that shows all players, their number and fouls they have.

I have also an AdminPanel component which consists of ControlPanel component, MiddlePanel component and VotingPanel component. Here's the screen of AdminPanel component
And the problem I have is that when I'm setting foul on the AdminPanel. It shows here, but it doesn't on the UserPanel.
So, when I'm clicking on button "Поставить фол" on AdminPanel, I have this view for player 6:
But on UserPanel I have this view for player 6:

So the state.gameReducer.players wasn't updated and the component wasn't rerendered. The expected view for UserPanel: 
I should notice that I'm using react-router-dom and UserPanel is on the localhost:3000 and AdminPanel is on the localhost:3000/admin. I don't know why is it so, because the UserPanel and the MiddlePanel are subscribed to the gameSlice global state. Here's UserPanel component code:
import React from "react";
import Player from "./Player";
import Timer from "./Timer";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

export default function UserPanel() {
    
    const players = useSelector((state) => state.gameReducer.players);

    return (
        <div className="user-panel">
            <div className="container">
                <h1>Mafia NUZP</h1>
                <div className="players-container">
                    {players.map(player => {
                        return <Player number={player.number} fouls={player.fouls} chosen={player.chosen}/>
                    })}
                </div>
                <Timer />
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

MiddlePanel code:
import React from "react";
import Player from "../../Player";
import Role from "../../Role";
import Timer from "../../Timer";
import TimerControls from "./TimerControls";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

export default function MiddlePanel(props) {
    const players = useSelector((state) => state.gameReducer.players);
    let chosenPlayer = players.findIndex(player => player.chosen === true);

    return(
        <div className="middle-panel">
        <div className="chosen-player-container">
            <h1>Player {chosenPlayer + 1}</h1>
        </div>
        <div className="players-container">
            {players.map(player => {
              return <Player number={player.number} role={<Role role={player.role}/>} fouls={player.fouls} chosen={player.chosen}/>  
            })}
        </div>
        <div className="timer-container">
            <Timer />
            <TimerControls />
        </div>
    </div>
    )
}

ControlPanel code:
import React from "react";
import { setFoul, setRole } from "../../features/game/gameSlice";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";

export default function ControlPanel() {
    
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    return(
        <div className="control-panel">
        <button className="btn btn-dark" onClick={() => dispatch(setRole({role: "Д"}))}>Сделать доном</button>
        <button className="btn btn-secondary" onClick={() => dispatch(setRole({role: "М"}))}>Сделать мафией</button>
        <button className="btn btn-warning" onClick={() => dispatch(setRole({role: "Ш"}))}>Сделать шерифом</button>
        <button className="btn btn-danger" onClick={() => dispatch(setRole({role: "К"}))}>Сделать мирным</button>
        <button className="btn btn-light" onClick={() => dispatch(setFoul())}>Поставить фол</button>
        <button className="btn btn-primary">Выставить на голосование</button>
        <button className="btn btn-danger">Изгнать</button>
        <button className="btn btn-info">Следующий игрок</button>
        <button className="btn btn-info">Предыдущий игрок</button>
    </div>
    )
}

And gameSlice code:
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

let players = [
    {number: 1, fouls: [null, null, null, null], role: null, chosen: false},
    {number: 2, fouls: [null, null, null, null], role: null, chosen: false},
    {number: 3, fouls: [null, null, null, null], role: null, chosen: false},
    {number: 4, fouls: [null, null, null, null], role: null, chosen: false},
    {number: 5, fouls: [null, null, null, null], role: null, chosen: false},
    {number: 6, fouls: [null, null, null, null], role: null, chosen: true},
    {number: 7, fouls: [null, null, null, null], role: null, chosen: false},
    {number: 8, fouls: [null, null, null, null], role: null, chosen: false},
    {number: 9, fouls: [null, null, null, null], role: null, chosen: false},
    {number: 10, fouls: [null, null, null, null], role: null, chosen: false}]

let admin = {

}

const initialState = {
    players: players,
    adminPanel: admin
}

const gameSlice = createSlice({
    name: "game",
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        setRole(state, action) {
            let {role} = action.payload
            let chosenIndex = state.players.findIndex(player => player.chosen === true);
            state.players[chosenIndex].role = role;
        },

        setFoul(state, action) {
            let chosenIndex = state.players.findIndex(player => player.chosen === true);
            
            let foulIndex = state.players[chosenIndex].fouls.findIndex(foul => foul === null);

            state.players[chosenIndex].fouls[foulIndex] = "F";
        },
    }
})

export const {setFoul, setRole} = gameSlice.actions

export default gameSlice.reducer


I don't see any overt issues in the code you have shared in the post. What exactly is the issue or problem? Please [edit] to clarify what the exact specific issue is, and include the reproduction steps.

@DrewReese I've edited

How do you get from one instance of the panel that has the correct state and rendered UI to the other instance of the panel that doesn't have it? What are the exact reproduction steps? Is it too much trouble to create a running Codesandbox demo of the app that we could inspect live?

it sounds to me like you might have two tabs open, one on the admin panel and one on the user panel.  Is this correct?

@ScottZ yeah, it's correct. I have UserPanel on localhost:3000 and AdminPanel on localhost:3000/admin

@DrewReese here is Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/p/github/Dreyclin/mafia-nuzp

I have edited my answer below.  Global state only tracks and updates in that particular instance of the app.  If you have two tabs open you have disconnected instances of the app open. Think of it as two separate users on two separate computers in two separate locations in the world.

React app state is a per/instance scenario. In other words, each user of the app has their own copy of it and its own global state. If you are implementing a multi-user app then each instance of the app needs to push updates to a centralized location, e.g. a server/DB/socket/etc that all instances of the app are working with.

If you return an array of components, you need to pass a key prop to those components so react can keep track of them.
 {players.map(player => {
              return <Player key={player.number} number={player.number} role={<Role role={player.role}/>} fouls={player.fouls} chosen={player.chosen}/>  
            })}

Once you pass a key prop, react will be able to correctly track the state of each component in the array.  The key needs to be a completely unique value that will not be duplicated by any of the other items in the array.  Often the key will be the id of the value in the DB.  Also, resist the urge to use the map index as the key.  That can work, but can also cause difficult to find bugs.
With your edit, it sounds like you have two different tabs open in your browser, and expect the state of one tab to be reflected in the other tab. If this is the case, these are technically two different users on different computers in different locations in the world.  Redux alone can not synchronize data between different application instances.  To synchronize data between application instances there will need to be an API which those instances can subscribe to for updates.
